# Extracted real estate listing data from xml to display

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, custom-post-type

I am developing one real-estate website using WordPress for one client.
Client has given my XML feed which contains properties. 
I have extracted data from the feed using SimpleXML by creating a new template.
I am confused regarding the next step?
Should I save data in database by creating a new table or start with Custom Post type?

Please guide me. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should save that data inside database.

You want something like this

```
id | title | description | location | availability
--------------------------------------------------
```

and after that you can work with the data on your website.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable reply. 
Should I make another table in database or use any existing? Would it effect default WordPress functionality?

Comment: Wordpress by default does not have table structured like that so u would definintly need to make one, by yourself or by using some sort of plugin for WP. Try to search Worpress custom database table